# When does $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{p(p+1)\cdots(p+n-1)}{n!n^q}$ converge/diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

When does
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{p(p+1)\cdots(p+n-1)}{n!n^q}$$ converge/diverge?
Please note that $p$ may be negative. Thanks!

Comment: [tag:calculus] has nothing to do with this question. Please read the tag description before applying a tag.

Comment: $p$ and $q$ are reals. My initial idea was to use Raabe criterion, it works for similiar series, but this one is a bit more complecated.

Answer (score 0):

If *p* is either zero or a negative integer, then the sum converges, since, starting with a certain value of *n*, all its terms will be $0$. If not, then multiply and divide the series by $(p-1)!$, and use [Stirling's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Comment: $p$ is not assumed to be an integer. Better write $\Gamma(p)$.